# Visually removing object from large list using jQuery and Rails3

Tags: jquery, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a page with many Objects listed, each a separate TR tablerow, and a separate form for saving that Object. I want to make it so when the user clicks Save for that tablerow, that row is removed from the screen (and saved).

All the code for saving and returning success+error works fine, but what I want to do is visually remove that Object from the list. The user could choose *any* object in the long list, not just the first or last, so I would need to arbitrarily fade/remove any  when they hit Submit.

Is this possible? Below is the code for the individual row, the page could have 30+ of these.

```
<tr class="objectRow">
 <td>
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/objects" class="new_object" data-remote="true" id="new_object" method="post">
      <......input select boxes go here...........>
     <p><input id="object_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Create Object" /></p>
  </form>           
 </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
("#object_submit").parent().parent().parent().parent().hide();
```

or

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) - Get the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.

```
$("input [type=submit]").click(function(){
  $(this).closest('tr.objectRow').hide();
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of these work. I checked on '$(this)' and it contains the entire DOMWindow, not the current <tr>. The first line gave the error '#object_submit' has no parent' (and wouldn't this be a non-dynamic approach?. The second line doesn't do anything, but if I try it in console I get an error 'Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined'